Styled components typed by interface error
I using SC with react, decided to type an element with interface, but this error occurs:
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `completed`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: completed="false" or completed={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with completed={condition && value}, pass completed={condition ? value : undefined} instead.


export const TaskText = styled.span<ITaskStatus>`
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.sizes.xl}px;
  color: ${({ completed }) => (completed ? '#a9a9a9' : '#333')};
  text-decoration: ${({ completed }) => (completed ? 'line-through' : 'none')};
`

export interface ITaskStatus {
  completed?: boolean
}

Any advices on this?
I've tried to replace the interface generic with
export const TaskText = styled.span<{ completed?: boolean }>

but error still occurs

In styled-components, when passing a prop to a component, the prop is typically evaluated as a string. This behavior can sometimes lead to unexpected results, especially when dealing with boolean props.
There is a way to solve this:
First you need to change the type to a string and then in the ternary since now is not a boolean you need to check if the string is "true" or "false"
export interface ITaskStatus {
  completed?: string
}

export const TaskText = styled.span<ITaskStatus>`
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.sizes.xl}px;
  color: ${({ completed }) => (completed === "true" ? '#a9a9a9' : '#333')};
  text-decoration: ${({ completed }) => (completed === "true" ? 'line-through' : 'none')};

Now you need to change the prop completed in the component where you are using the SC:
inside the component:
const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState<boolean>(false);

// This to pass "true" or "false" that is needed in the SC
const booleanToString = (value: boolean) => (value ? 'true' : 'false');

...some code...

<TaskText completed={booleanToString(isCompleted)}>
...some code...
</TaskText>

...some code...

